# Only secure origins are allowed - Local Network

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ssl, https

I'm getting the error: "registerServiceWorker.js:71 Error during service worker registration: DOMException: Only secure origins are allowed (see: https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/prefer-secure-origins-for-powerful-new-features)." This is on the console of a React JS web app.

I understand that to resolve this error I would need to setup HTTPS on my API server, the problem is that I am running this app on the local network and it is served through a local IP address. This web app also uses data that is only exposed locally so I can not host it externally and get an SSL cert for a domain.

From what I've read on StackOverflow I could create a self-signed certificate but this would show users an SSL error page on most browsers.

What would be the best option to resolve this issue?